# Can I obtain the rendered html of a gridview via webService call?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, web-services

Is there a simple of of calling a webService method that Rebinds an asp.Net GridView control and returns its rendered html so that I can refresh the region that contains the gridview on the page?

I can use jQuery.Load maybe but on the server side how can I obtain a specific control's rendered block?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Gridview.RenderControl() method.

```
 System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();    
 System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);    
 GridView2.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
       // Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the
       // specified ASP.NET server control at run time.
       // No code required here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this in the webmethod.

```
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        //Your Logic to fill dataset/datatable
        DataTable dt=new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Index"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            DataRow row=dt.NewRow();
            row["Index"]=i;
            row["Name"]="dummyData"+i.ToString();
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        //bind the gridview
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
        //get the rendered HTML
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter writer=new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter txt = new HtmlTextWriter(writer);
        gv.RenderControl(txt);
        return sb.ToString();
```